# Angular Way to set a form's enctype to application/json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, enctype

I want to submit form data via a POST request. The form submission needs to trigger a download, [so I cannot do this with any Javascript request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148856/using-angular-to-download-a-file-via-ajax). So calling a function which uses the `$http` service is out.

To make matters more difficult, I need the corresponding backend route in Node.js to be able to decode a JSON object optimally without using `bodyParser.urlencoded()` but it can use `bodyParser.json()`.

I've been looking at the [Angular documentation for Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) as well as for the [Form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) but I don't see a way to set the `enctype` to JSON. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[JSON form encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) is a abandoned specification with, as far as I know, zero browser support in the wild.

So no, it is not possible.